# Does clustering belong to the domain of data mining or to the domain of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, reference-request

**Question 1.** Does clustering belong to the domain of data mining or to the domain of machine learning? Or to both domains?

**Question 2.** Depending on the answer to Question 1, could you please suggest a good reference about it as well?

I mean:

- *Either* a reference on "clustering belongs to the domain of data mining"
- *Or* a reference on "clustering belongs to the domain of machine learning"
- *Or* a reference on "clustering lies at the interface between data mining and machine learning"

**Note.** If not possible to reply to both questions, I would greatly appreciate a reply to Question 1 at least.

Comment: Can you define "data mining" and "machine learning"? You might find that these are just labels meaning different things to different people.

Comment: Please see below the definitions:
**Data Mining definition by Cios et al. (Ref.(1))** "What is Data Mining? The aim of data mining is to make sense of large amounts of mostly unsupervised data, in some domain." 
**Machine Learning definition by Alpaydin (Ref.(2))** "Machine learning is programming computers to optimize a performance criterion using example data or past experience"
**Data Mining and Machine Learning relationship by Alpaydin (Ref.(2))** "Application of machine learning methods to large databases is called
data mining. "

Comment: **Ref. (1).** Cios, K., Pedrycz, W., Swiniarski, R. & Kurgan, L. Data Mining: A Knowledge Discovery Approach (Springer US, 2007), Page 3.

**Ref. (2).** Alpaydin, E. Introduction to Machine Learning, fourth edition. Adaptive Computation and Machine Learning series (MIT Press, 2020), Pages 2 and 3

Comment: Btw, those "definitions" in **Ref. (1)** and **Ref. (2)** are not "real" definitions, in my humble opinion, but just "foggy workarounds" related to both data mining and machine learning.

Comment: The problem with these definitions is that unsupervised learning, which clustering is a part of, is in both definitions, so technically there is no difference between the two. The first definition mentions unsupervised learning directly, while the second mentions optimization criterions, and clustering also optimizes criterions, for ex. k-means optimizes within-cluster variances.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2974951  :-) I might then think that the phrase, "clustering lies at the interface between data mining and machine learning", would be correct.